# How to execute Oracle query with parameters in Airflow Python Operator

Tags: python, airflow, cx-oracle, bind-variables

I'm using Oracle connection of Airflow.

```
import cx_Oracle
from airflow.providers.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
```

The below code has Worked :

```
last_snap_date = '2021-03-23'
        value = hook.get_records (sql="select distinct ven as name from Execution Metrics  where date > TO_DATE(\'"+last_snap_date2+"\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\')")
```

But The Requirements was top using Bind Variables .
Here , last_snap_date2 is the Varible i  want to pass to method 'get_records' Using sql bind Variables . I tried multiple steps but failed .

```
def _process():

    print('*********** Oracle Conection ***************')   
    #Oracle Conection
    hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id="Oracle")

    last_snap_date = '2021-03-23'
    value = hook.get_records (sql="select distinct ven as name from Execution Metrics  where date > TO_DATE(\'"+last_snap_date2+"\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\')")

with DAG(
dag_id='OracleQuery',
start_date=dates.days_ago(2),
schedule_interval='@monthly',
catchup=False,
) as dag :

    task_a =PythonOperator(
        task_id="QueryIntegration",
        python_callable=_process
)
```

Documentation for the get_records Methods for Reference :

```
def get_records(self, sql, parameters=None):
        """
        Executes the sql and returns a set of records.

        :param sql: the sql statement to be executed (str) or a list of
            sql statements to execute
        :type sql: str or list
        :param parameters: The parameters to render the SQL query with.
        :type parameters: dict or iterable
        """
        with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
            with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
                if parameters is not None:
                    cur.execute(sql, parameters)
                else:
                    cur.execute(sql)
                return cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: At a guess, try something like `hook.get_records("select mycol from mytable where mydate > TO_DATE(:bv,'YYYY-MM-DD')", {'bv': '2021-03-23'})`